# concatenating a uint8_t array into uint32_t array in C

Tags: c, arrays, concatenation

This might have been asked before. But I'll ask anyway. If someone could direct me to something relevant, that would also be great.

So, if I have:

```
uint8_t src[] = {34, 56, 31, 89, 11, 32, 67, 89};
```

Is this possible to get something like this through concatenation:

```
uint32_t dst[] = {34563189, 11326789};
```

If yes, how? I saw a question for casting uint8_t array into a uint32_t but I need to put the 4-bytes chunk side by side into a uint32_t array. Thanks!

Comment: Are these supposed to be hex values?

Comment: @nneonneo If they are decimal values, then I guess ouah's answer just perfectly fine. But I am also curious what would be the solution if they were to be hex. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really are working with decimal values:

```
uint32_t dst[] = {1000000 * src[0] +10000 * src[1] + 100 * src[2] + src[3],
                  1000000 * src[4] +10000 * src[5] + 100 * src[6] + src[7]};
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer! How would it change if these are hex values?

Comment: @xMaster Then you would need to `<< 8` and ` <<16` and `<<24` instead of  `* 100` and  `* 10000`  and `* 1000000`.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion,

1. use `snprintf()` to print individual `uint8_t`s to a `char` array.
2. use `strtol()` to convert the *array* to integer.